# Why does the templated control inside a pivot inside a navigation view frame get an actual width and height of zero upon navigation?

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a Win2d CanvasControl set as the content of a PivotItem inside a Pivot. That Pivot is inside a Blank Page construct and the Page is loaded as a NavigationView content frame. When I navigate to another frame in the navigation view and then navigate back to my page with the Pivot the Pivot.SelectedItem gets a Draw event notification where the actual width and actual height are correct. The other PivotItems inside the Pivot also get a Draw event, but their actual width and height are zero. I assume this is because they are not visible and this is a trait of the xaml framework. However, important to note that their .IsVisiable property is set as visible.

What is it called when these controls are set at zero actual height and width? Why does the xaml framework do this? Is there a property I can check to see that it's set to zero by zero?

Comment: Are you looking at `Width` and `Height` or `ActualWidth` and `ActualHeight`.. They get updated asynchronously as layout update settles.